# monitor ActiveMQ via JMX API

Tags: java, linux, activemq-classic

I'm trying to monitor ActiveMQ via JMX  I have added the following, to enable JXM to my startup script.

```
# **** Uncomment to enable jmx ****
wrapper.java.additional.n=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1616
wrapper.java.additional.n=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
wrapper.java.additional.n=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

I'm trying to test the connection by using this tool  cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar which provides telnet like interface for JXM

```
# java -jar cmdline-jmxclient-0.10.3.jar - 10.10.130.111:1616

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.10.130.111; nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:355)
    at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:268)
    at org.archive.jmx.Client.execute(Client.java:225)
    at org.archive.jmx.Client.main(Client.java:154)
Caused by: javax.naming.ServiceUnavailableException [Root exception is java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 10.10.130.111; nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused]
    at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:118)
    at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(GenericURLContext.java:203)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:409)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(RMIConnector.java:1915)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(RMIConnector.java:1884)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:289)
```

Even tho authentication is set to false, yet I'm getting connection exception.

Netstat shows its listing to all available interfaces & iptables /SELinux are disabled

```
#netstat -ntlp 

tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.10.130.111:61616  :::*      LISTEN      29917/java
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: What this tells you is that a java process is listening on port 61616. Which is the default configuration port for the openwire connector. So, is your question why you do not see the process listening on port 1616 which you gave as the JMX port?

Comment: My question, is that I can't connect to that port, and I keep getting connection refused message.

Comment: Well, if netstat does not bring up port 1616 then there is simply nothing to connect to. There must be a problem with your JMX configuration. I am not using the service wrapper to run ActiveMQ so I cannot comment on the correctness of your config.